# Open table in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table on my page.I want to open a table in model to display  particular record when i click on a td. Below is my code my problem is when i use this code model open successfully but my page table layout is not display properly.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-default">
<?php 
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from class_review as a left join class_user_details as b on a.list_id = b.id group by list_id");
//$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from class_review as a left join class_user_details as b on a.list_id = b.id left join class_users as c on a.user_id=c.id");
//echo "select * from class_review as a left join class_user_details as b on a.list_id = b.id left join class_users as c on a.user_id=c.id";
?>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Shop Name</th>
<!--<th>User Name</th>-->
<th>Total Review </th>
<th>Average Rate</th>
<th>See All Review</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $i=1;while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['shop_name'] ; ?></td>
<?php $list_id=$row['list_id']; $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) from class_review where list_id=$list_id");
$fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query); ?>
<td><?php echo $fetch[0] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['rate_point'] ; ?></td>
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1<?php echo $row['list_id'] ; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Reviews</button></td>
</tr>
<!--My Stuff start -->
<div id="myModal1<?php echo $row['list_id'] ; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Review </th>
<th>Average Rate</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>dd</td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>ee</td>
<td>dfd</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button id="dialoge<?php echo $row['id'] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--My Stuff end -->
<?php $i++; } ?>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

your modal table is not responsive,make a structure like this

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

     //rest of code

    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: @this.grish still not working when i use responsive classs

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @thsi.grish when i am using modal code out side of loop this working well but it is mandatory to keep in loop.

Comment: what was that? blank fiddle? put your code there remove Php from code make it pure Html with some static data, and exact structure